# ¿Como implementar un cargar pagina de nuevo al hacer un insert o update o delete?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy realizando un **CRUD** y quisiera que a el insertar actualizar o eliminar los datos en mi formiulario al hacerlo la pagina se vuelva a actualizar, que no se vuelva a ejecutar el insert o delete si le doy f5 que la pagina haga el insert y se actualice Por ejemplo este es mi la funcion de mi boton

```
namespace CapaPresentacion
{
    public partial class ArticuloEnterate : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                CargarLista();
            }
        }

        public void CargarLista()
        {

            IList<Enterate> Get_Enterate;

            Get_Enterate = EnterateLN.getInstance().Get_Enterate();
            Carga(Get_Enterate, ListaArticulo, "Id_ent", "titu_ent");

        }
        public static void Carga(object coleccion, DropDownList combo, string pDataValueField, string pDataTextField)
        {
            try
            {
                combo.Items.Clear();
                combo.DataValueField = pDataValueField;
                combo.DataTextField = pDataTextField;
                combo.DataSource = coleccion;
                combo.DataBind();
                combo.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Seleccione El Articulo", "-1"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }


        protected void ListaArticulo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Enterate Get_Enterate1;

            //Ejecutar el get para mostrar los datos//

            try
            {
                TituloArticuloEnterate.InnerText = ListaArticulo.SelectedItem.Text;

                Get_Enterate1 = EnterateLN.getInstance().Get_Enterate1(Convert.ToInt32(ListaArticulo.SelectedItem.Value));

                ParrafoArticuloEnterate.InnerText = Get_Enterate1.parf_ent;

                filepreview.Src = Get_Enterate1.img_ent;

                FechaArticuloEnterate.Value = Get_Enterate1.fech_art_ent.ToString("  dd/ MM / yyyy");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
            }

        }

        public Enterate GetEntity()

        {
            //Metodo Para Actualizar Articulos 
            Enterate objEnterate = new Enterate();
            objEnterate.Id_ent = Convert.ToInt32(ListaArticulo.SelectedItem.Value);
            objEnterate.titu_ent = TituloArticuloEnterate.InnerText;
            objEnterate.img_ent =  filepreview.Src;
            objEnterate.parf_ent = ParrafoArticuloEnterate.InnerText;
            objEnterate.fech_art_ent = DateTime.Now;
            return objEnterate;
        }


        protected void actualizar1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

            //Actualizacion Del Articulo Enterate

            Enterate objEnterate = GetEntity();

            //Enviar A CapaLogicaNegocio

            bool response = EnterateLN.getInstance().Enterate_Update(objEnterate);

            if (response == true)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Articulo Actualizado Exitosamente')</script>");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Error Al Actualizar El Articulo')</script>");
            }
        }

        protected void eliminar1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //Eliminar el Articulo Enterate

             Enterate objEnterate = GetEntity();

            //Enviar A CapaLogicaNegocio

            bool response = EnterateLN.getInstance().Enterate_Delete(objEnterate);

            if (response == true)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Articulo Eliminado Exitosamente')</script>");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Error Al Eliminar El Articulo')</script>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar ese efecto despues de realizar la operacion de `insert` o `delete` realiza un `redirect` a la pagina para que la recargue, de esta forma el F5 lo que hara es realizar la ultima operaicon o sea la carga de la pagina y no la operacion de insert o delete.

```
public void button_Click(...)
{
     //aqui realizas el insert

     Response.Redirect("ListEntidad.aspx");
}
```

Si estas en la pagina que lista las entidades, luego de insertar redirecciona a la pagina que lista la entidad, no te quedes en la pagina de alta o edicion

[[ASP.NET] GridView – Edición Empleados](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2011/05/aspnet-gridview-edicion-empleados.html)

En en el articulo implemento justamente esto que comento, se selecciona la entidad en la lista, pero luego de la operacion se vuelve al listado, asi el F5 no te afecta

Comment: Con el  **Response.Redirect("ListEntidad.aspx");** no me permite colocar alertas con alert ?

Comment: es que no necesitas ninguna alerta, cuando la operacion se realiza al redireccionar la listas tendra la entidad ya creada

Comment: Es como para darle la información a el usuario de que se creo o se actualizo o se borro lo que pedia

Comment: pero si lo ve listado ya sabe que se creo. Igual si lo nacesitas puedes realizar el redirect desde codigo cliente usando `window.localtion.href=´listadoentidad.aspx´` esto lo pones despues del alert